# What is this union of integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m,n,p,q$ be four integers such that ${\rm gcd}(m, n)={\rm gcd}(p,q)=1$.

Is there a nice description of the set 
$$
 \bigcup_{(k,\ell)\in \mathbb Z^2} \big\{{\rm gcd}(pm+\ell q, pn+kq)\big\}\; ?
$$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean with, for example, $8\cup12$?

Comment: Question edited.